# Bower - O que é, qual sua utilidade e como usar?

Tags: front-end, bower

Em arquivos de projetos e principalmente frameworks front-end já vi muito, muito mesmo o arquivo **bower.json** e acredito que ele seja um arquivo como `composer.json`, `package.json`, `Gruntfile.js`, `README.md`, então gostaria de saber:

- O que é Bower?
- Qual sua utilidade?
- Como usar?
- (Opcional) Quais vantagens posso ganhar utilizando-o?

Comment: Acho que todas as respostas podem ser encontradas no [readme do projeto](https://github.com/bower/bower#bower---a-package-manager-for-the-web) ou nos [issues](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues). Você está buscando algo em português, é isso?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso. Não sei muito de inglês e os tradutores não fazem uma boa tradução...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ele é um gerenciador de pacotes, ou seja serve para instalar ou desintalar  pacotes. É possível criar uma lista de dependências que serão usadas no seu projeto em um arquivo `.bowerrc` quando for instalar em qualquer ambiente, as depenências serão instaladas automaticamente com o comando bower install.

Podemos dizer que a função do arquivo `.bowerrc` no Bower, é a mesma do `package.json` no NPM. A principal diferença é que o bower serve para instalar dependências que serão utilizadas no cliente (como jquery, angular, bootstrap) enquanto o NPM lida com dependências de servidor (grunt, mongodb, express). Inclusive, o Bower roda em servidor, então ele mesmo pode ser instalado por NPM.

Para saber como instalar e utilizar na prática, recomendo o [site oficial](http://bower.io/).
Boa sorte.